# Vue.js & bxslider, The slider doesn’t load. Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Tags: vue.js, bxslider

I am using browserify and i want to use bxslider. When i had all the templates in a single file (index.html), it was working. Now i am using browserify to build it so i have vue components. I want to use bx slider in a vue component.

**slider.vue**

```
<ul class="bxslider">
      <li>
             <img src="img/thumb-01.jpg"/>
       </li>
</ul>
```

**index.html**

```
<link href="plugins/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <div id="app"></div>
       <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
  });
</script>
```

I couldn't get the bxslider, i try to use it as a function in a component, alse try to use it in a seperate file. Any suggestions please?

Comment: You will need to ensure that your document ready function is called after vue is done with rendering.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$(document).ready()` is executed before the vue.js code. You need to replace this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

with

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
  },100);
});
```